# how to remove &nbsp; character in php? (str_replace function not working)

Tags: php, str-replace

"contentDetails" has following data in it:

```
<p>This is data sample.&nbsp;</p><p>Second part of the paragraph.&nbsp;</p>
```

str_replace is not working here. Please take a look.

here is how my xml strucuture in php looks like:

```
$xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">;
$xml = '<root>';
$xml = '<myData>';
$xml .= <content> . str_replace("&nbsp;", "", htmlentities($_POST[contentDetails])) . </content>
$xml = '</myData>';
$xml = '</root>';
```

Comment: Provide result of `var_dump($_POST[contentDetails]);`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `contentDetails` actually contains:

```
<p>This is data sample.&nbsp;</p><p>Second part of the paragraph.&nbsp;</p>
```

(`$nbsp;` replaced with `&nbsp;`)

Your problem is that when you call `htmlentities` on `contentDetails` it converts `&nbsp;` into `&amp;nbsp;`, so your `str_replace` won't find any matches. To solve the problem, call `str_replace` before `htmlentities`:

```
$xml .= '<content>' . htmlentities(str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $_POST['contentDetails'])) . '</content>';
```

Note that associative array keys should be enclosed in quotes; this will cause a warning now but in future PHP versions will be an error.

Comment: yes, actually contentDetails has &nbsp;  Not $nbsp;
tried your recommendation, still no luck. Any other tips or ideas to fix this? thanks.

Comment: @Kyle sorry about slow response, it's been night here. If contentDetails does contain what I've described in the question, this code should work. See this demo: https://3v4l.org/oYsZ5. If you're still having issues, can you try to modify the demo to show them? That would make it easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

The htmlentities() function converts &nbsp; to &amp;nbsp;  --- so try this...

`str_replace("&amp;nbsp;", "", htmlentities($_POST[contentDetails]))`

Comment: tried this still no luck, checked that field "contentDetails" - it appears as "&nbsp;".
any other tips or ideas to resolve this? thanks.